# Script inside of script tag in html page is not getting executed when used with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I am building a single page web application using Angular and UI-Router. In my index.html page, I currently have these three elements, a navbar directive, a ui-view and a footer directive as shown below:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <cep-navbar></cep-navbar>
        </div>

        <ui-view></ui-view>

        <div class="row">
            <cep-footer></cep-footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- All the bower script dependencies-->
    <!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- All the custom script dependencies-->
    <!-- build:js js/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- inject:template:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

</body>
```

Module which contains the navbar directive defines the route as follows:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('CEPAdmin.base.components')
        .config(['$stateProvider', routeConfig]);

    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'src/app/pages/search/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController'
        });
    }
})();
```

I load in the search state by clicking on one of the links in navbar directive which injects of the search.html page in ui-view on the index.html page. But the problem is the script inside the script tag never executes. Here is my search.html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      console.log('Test me');
      window.alert('Test me bro');
</script>
<h1>Hello World!!</h1>
```

Why is it that the script inside of scripts tag in search.html page not getting executed whenever my search state is loaded?

Link to plunk : [https://plnkr.co/edit/RaX5Jsd5zqAfbwGE0i8o](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaX5Jsd5zqAfbwGE0i8o)

Comment: Have you considered running your script inside your SearchController instead of inlining it in the template?

`function SearchController($scope) {
         alert("hi");
        ...`

Comment: @Oliver Barnwell it will work from the controller. But my requirement is I want to reference 3rd party script file from the partial view.

Comment: As in, include an external JS file? If so why not load the 3rd party script file when the page first loads instead of loading in script files on the fly as the user navigates your website?

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigating it further, I got to know that stripped down version of jquery that angular uses (jQLite) has some DOM limitations which prevents it from executing a script file in partial view.

**Solution**

Reference a jQuery script before referencing Angular in your index.html. This makes angular to use jQuery instead of jQlite. Just doing this solved my problem.